# Visual studio 2015 does not recompile under DEBUG

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, rebuild

Such a problem. Studio under debug runs the previous version that was compiled. In the release assembly all the rules. The check boxes in the configuration manager are. In the settings of the studio where the assembly, put always recompile. Folders with assemblies and an obj folder deleted. Nothing helps. Even if I change the location of components on the form, in debug it's still the old version. Although even in the designer everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to check your project output path in your project, maybe it was not the real output path you have deleted, for example, the general C# app, the output path would be the Bin\Debug in default.

Before you run your app, please also clean and rebuild your project, and then run it again. To make sure that whether the output files were updated, you could also visit the modify data of all files. Maybe you don't enable the build option in the configuration manager.

If still no help, just create a blank solution, and then add all project files to this new solution, and clean and rebuild the solution, run it. And then just modify or change the app code, re-build it, visit the result.

Comment: I rebuilt the project from a new empty project, to which the current one was added. Now x64 (debug-release) and x86 (release) are started normally. In x86, still does not update. The paths for the output files are. The checkboxes in the configuration manager are also everywhere

Comment: @user1667616, If it works well in other platform using the debugging mode, I think we would think about the project itself, which kind of app did you run/debug? Whether your app has certain references which were not compiled using the same platform target as this one? Do you really stop debugging before you run or debug it if you don't enable the E&C under Tools->Options->Debugging?

Comment: @user1667616, Would you please share the latest information about this issue?